# Order of properties within Firebase database objects

Tags: database, firebase, nosql

I've been making an app backend with some data. I'm curious why do the properties of these objects get shuffled like this whenever I make a GET request to the database?

```
{
    "screamID": "3hUYKDFdUzt055G3tp7i",
    "createdAt": {
        "_seconds": 1596446283,
        "_nanoseconds": 119000000
    },
    "body": "new scream 6",
    "userHandle": "new"
},
{
    "screamID": "KinWHznfRmGd4tJpsucV",
    "createdAt": {
        "_seconds": 1596438857,
        "_nanoseconds": 521000000
    },
    "userHandle": "new",
    "body": "new scream 4"
},
{
    "screamID": "aZM8sX1sgCOOymVMx7Uo",
    "body": "new scream 3",
    "userHandle": "new",
    "createdAt": {
        "_seconds": 1596199717,
        "_nanoseconds": 251000000
    }
}
```

It doesn't really affect anything, I'm just curious why it returns them like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map type objects with key/value pairs have no inherent ordering (except for those types of maps that explicitly guarantee one, which Firebase does not do).  Internally, Maps are going to use a hash table to allow you to quickly find values for any key.  They are not using an ordered array, because scanning that array sequentially for each lookup would be unnecessarily time consuming.

The way hash tables are typically implemented, the order of iteration of key/value pairs is going to be dependent on:

1. The implementation details of the hash
2. The number of entries in the hash
3. The order in which keys were added to it

Since a map handed to you from an API doesn't typically give you a guarantee about any of these things, you can expect the order to vary from situation to situation.

The way [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) operate is fundamental computer science.  If you want to learn more, there are plenty of educational materials out there.